# Why cannot pass the class extended from another generic class as generic class?

Tags: java, oop, generics, extends, generic-programming

I develop some big project. Some parts of my code:

1)

```
private final ObjectPool<ProcessorMechanicsRoom> processorsPool;
... new ProcessorMechanicsRoom(processorsPool);
```

2. 

```
public class ProcessorMechanicsRoom
        extends ProcessorMechanics<ProcessMechanicsRoom, IMechanicsRoom, IMechanicsRoomCallback> {
    ...
    public ProcessorMechanicsRoom(ObjectPool<ProcessorMechanicsRoom> pool) {
}
    super(pool); // the problem is here
}
```

3. 

```
public class ProcessorMechanics
        <P extends ProcessMechanics<M,C>, M extends IAMechanics<C>, C extends IAMechanicsCallback>
        extends Processor<P> {
    private final ObjectPool<ProcessorMechanics<P,M,C>> pool;
    ...
    public ProcessorMechanics(ObjectPool<ProcessorMechanics<P,M,C>> pool) {...}
    ...

}
```

The problem is that ObjectPool<ProcessorMechanicsRoom> cannot be passed into super-constructor (code 2). So i am confused.

Comment: Edit your question and show the full text of the compilation error.  On a design note, having both ProcessMechanics and ProcessorMechanics as class names, as well as ProcessMechanicsRoom and ProcessorMechanicsRoom, is quite confusing.  I may try replacing those names in my own private copy of your code, to clarify the problem, but for now, it’s so hard to tell them apart that I gave up on trying.  You will get more help if your code is easier to understand.

Comment: logically, ProcessorMechanicsRoom can be casted as ProcessorMechanics<...>. But my ide (intellij) display it as error. Is so logically!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's this thing called variance.

Let's use some types we are all familiar with:

`java.lang.Integer extends java.lang.Number extends java.lang.Object`

### Covariance

In a covariant system, you can write:

`Number x = new Integer();`

but you cannot write:

`Integer y = new Number();`

As you might surmise, basic assignment and such in java is all covariant. But that's not the only way to do it.

### Contravariance

In a contravariant system, you **cannot write**:

`Number x = new Integer();`

but on the flipside, this actually works:

`Integer y = new Number();`

### Invariance

This is the inflexible one; in this one, neither works. The only thing you can do is:

`Integer y = new Integer();`

### Okay, so, what about generics?

Whereas java is covariant for basic stuff, generics isn't. Generics is contravariant, or covariant, or invariant, depending on how you write the generics.

- Covariant: `List<? extends Number> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // legal`
- Contravariant: `List<? super Integer> list = new ArrayList<Number>(); // legal`
- Invariant: `List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // only integer will do here`

You've picked invariant. So only `ProcessorMechanics` will do; your `ProcessorMechanicsRoom` is a subclass, and therefore you can't do that unless your type relationship allows covariance, and it does not. Make that `? extends` and it'll work.

### Um, wtf? Why???

Because... life. That is how real life works.

Imagine it did not. I can do this, then, and break everything:

```
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Number> numbers = ints; // MARK THIS LINE!
numbers.add(new Double(5.0));
Integer x = ints.get(0); // ERROR!
```

In the above, if it had compiled and run, the last line would be an error, as the .get(0) call would retrieve a double value which isn't an integer. Fortunately, the above does not compile; the error occurs on the marked line. That's.. because the compiler should disallow this. Generics by its very nature **are invariant**.

Now, covariance can exist. For example, if you have a method that will sum up the result of invoking `.intValue()` on each of the Numbers inside, then you could write:

```
public int sumAll(List<Number> list) {
   int result = 0;
   for (Number n : list) result += n.intValue();
   return result;
}
```

but that's a bad way to write it; you've decreed that the parameter is invariant, thus, you cannot pass a `List<Integer>` to this thing. But the code is covariant. It would work just as well if you pass a list of integers. So, you should write that as `public int sumAll(List<? extends Number> numbers)` instead.

Here is an example of invariance:

```
public void addSumToEnd(List<Number> list) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (Number n : list) sum += n.intValue();
    list.add(sum);
}
```

Because we're adding a number here, you couldn't write `List<? extends Number>`. After all, we're adding an `int` and you can't do that to a `List<Double>`. The only acceptable lists you can feed in here are `List<Number>` and `List<Integer>` and there's no way to express that in java.

For lists, it's easy: "contravariance = adds" (`.add()`, `.addAll()`, etc), "covariance = reads", "invariance = does both". For other generified types it may not be that simple.

Presumably if your ProcessorMechanics class will only ever 'read', then you can make it covariant, and write:

```
public ProcessorMechanics(ObjectPool<? extends ProcessorMechanics<P, M, C>> pool) {...}
```